# How do I fix "Launch error" problem in eclipse java, while running a program?

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, java-17

[image]

While running first program got a launch error. I am sharing the code.

```
package firstpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class New {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\selenium servers files.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://selenium.dev");

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

I tried to run the first program to check whether eclipse is working or not. As I  completed my code then I clicked on run and the notification popups of launch error and I was expecting to run the program and get output according to the code. I am sharing you the image of launch notification.

The error notification after launch program...

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'firstproject'.
For input string: "H" under radix 16
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'firstproject'.
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "C:\Users\sales\eclipse-workspace\vishwa\firstproject\.classpath" (in directory "C:\Users\sales\eclipse-workspace\vishwa\firstproject"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "C:\Users\sales\eclipse-workspace\vishwa\firstproject\.classpath" (in directory "C:\Users\sales\eclipse-workspace\vishwa\firstproject"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: You didn’t share the image of launch notification but you shouldn’t anyway. Included the *text* of the error.

Comment: Previously I had added the image of notification, but I think it was not properly added. Therefore, I had again inserted the image. Thank you for informing me.

Comment: The screenshot of this dialog is not helpful. Click “Ok” and check what’s printed in the console view.

Comment: "Launching main" has encountered a problem dailog is arise.

Comment: I am editing the error just check in question discription.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the chromedriver.exe is not correct it seems.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\selenium servers files.exe");
```

Just point it to chromedriver.exe

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\selenium servers files\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Hope it solves the problem.

Comment: The new error occured: Error: Could not find or load main class 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: @Vishwa_097 can you check is java installed on machine?

Comment: yes java is installed in my PC.

Comment: Java 17 is installed in my PC and eclipse version 2019